# How to force gradle put dependent module in exploded mode in a WAR file

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a multi module project, and want to build it with gradle.
The module names are `biz` and `web`. The `biz` module is a module built by `java` plugin and web with `war` plugin.
The `web` module depends on `biz` module. So when I build the war file, gradle builds `biz` module and puts it as `biz.jar` in the resulting war file.

How should I configure gradle to put `biz` module as exploded mode in the resulting war file just like the `web` module classes itself?

Answer (score 0):

[edit] I've re-read your question and have modified my answer[/edit]

It seems like one solution would be to create a new configuration (`explodeDep` in the example below), include `biz` as a dependency under that configuration, and copy in the unzipped jar(s) from that dependency.

`web/build.gradle`:

```
description = 'Web'

configurations {
    explodeDep
    explodeDep.transitive = false
}

jar {
    into ('/') {
        from {
            configurations.explodeDep.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    explodeDep project (':biz')
}
```

Comment: hey, thankx for the answer. What if `biz` haas some transitive dependencies?

Comment: If you need to include the class files for dependencies of `biz` then they should probably be included in `biz.jar`. Then, extracting biz.jar (as we do above) will also include all those class files. This will make the build more modular.

Comment: I need those dependencies of `biz` be included in `WEB-INF\lib` as they are not my classes, but I think that `transitive=false` prevents it.